# Grep - Tabs + a pattern file

Tags: unix, grep

I'm looking to feed grep a pattern file with -f, but add a literal tab before and after each pattern (from the file). This method will allow me to grep for an exact column match, since I am dealing with a tab-separated file.

Yes, I have to use Grep. Awk and perl can't seem to handle my large pattern file.

And Yes, I could just add tabs to the pattern file, but I have many pattern files, so that would take a long time, but if all fails, that is what I'll do.

This should be useful for anyone looking to do an exact column match inside of a tsv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try adding the tabs "on the fly":

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/\\t/; s/$/\\t/' patterns) [args...]
```

to let `grep` interpret `\t` as tabs.

Comment: I'm not a sed expert, but is this doing <TAB><TAB>Pattern or <TAB>Pattern<TAB>? I'm curious because I need the latter, and what we have here runs fine, but grep exits with no matches. It's either not interpreting the tabs right, or the order of the tabs are off.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo The order is correct, try adding literal `\t` rather than real tabs as in my edit, maybe `grep` will like it better?

Comment: That'd be it! adding the extra \ does it! Thank you so much!